# i want 301 redirection to multiple pages

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

i want to change urls of my website, but there many pages, so i cant change them manually. 
so i need to change it from htaccess file.

i want to change the below url
http://demos.beusoft.com/ccjk/resource/arabic-translation-services/

with the 
http://demos.beusoft.com/ccjk/arabic-translation-services/

i am using wordpress. 
this is whole code ....

```
# BEGIN WordPress

RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^ccjk/resource/([^/]+)/$ demos.beusoft.com/ccjk/$1 [L,R=301]

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /ccjk/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /ccjk/index.php [L]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

please help, how to rewrite the url from the htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    # BEGIN WordPress


<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /ccjk/
RewriteRule ^resource/([^/]+)/$   http://demos.beusoft.com/ccjk/$1/  [L,R=302]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /ccjk/index.php [L]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: thanks for your reply sir, my site root address is  http://demos.beusoft.com/ccjk

firefox is throwing error 

The page isn't redirecting properly

Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

Comment: Don't post that in a comment. Edit your question and put them in there!

Comment: Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

Comment: link is live.. http://demos.beusoft.com/ccjk/resource/asturian-translation-services/

Comment: Did you copy all of my answer and deleted previous content?